# What would I call a "do not buy from" list?

Tags: translation

I would prefer not to use *nigralisto*, which I assume but cannot confirm is the Esperanto term for 'blacklist'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mi proponas *bojkotlisto*. [Bojkoto](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bojkoto) estas bona esperanto vorto kaj internacia komprenebla.

Answer (score 7):

*Nigra listo* (note, two words) is an established expression in Esperanto. (It's in PIV, anyway.) Of course, that doesn't mean you can't suggest an alternative.

Comment: I just searched vortaro.net and it's not in the PIV.

Comment: @Keir It's both under *nigra* and *listo*, provided in the examples.

Answer (score 4):

I would probably use something like:

> *Listo da evitindaj vendejoj*

But if you are looking for a single word, I cannot think of any decent one, as I think *evitindvendejlisto* sounds too weird. :)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps *sankcio listo*, a direct translation of "sanction list", which is a list of entities with whom you're prohibited from doing business with, by law.

Depending on the context, though, that might be too strong of a term.

Answer (score -2):

I think *nigralisto* as a single-word description is quite good, because its equivalent "blacklist" or literal transcription is widely spread in different languages, especially in computer-connected topics. Also it can be not only black-for-buying list, it's a bit more common. If to use full description - better use variant of Lyubomir Vasilev.

Comment: I think it might be too close to the English term. If other languages don't use it, the meaning might get lost: 'black' is not related at all to the actual purpose/form of the list, but opaquely to its function. In German, a 'schwarze Liste' would be a 'naughty list', if I remember correctly. So _nigralisto_ would be meaningless to anybody who is unfamiliar with the English term. Though I grant you that it is commonly used in computing these days.

Comment: Be sure to check PIV before answering, commenting, voting, and so on.

Comment: Words in Esperanto cannot be linked together with *a* in between. So, technically, *nigralisto* is gramatically wrong and should be two separate words — *nigra listo*. To make it a single word, you coud do: *nigrlisto*, *nigrolisto* or *nigro-listo*, but written like that I thinkg the meaning is lost.